# Resolving LinkError with jupyter_latex_envs Post-Link Script Failure in Conda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, ipython, python-3.11

I'm encountering a LinkError when trying to install jupyter_latex_envs via conda in my conda environment. The post-link script fails, and it seems related to an issue with type annotations in Python 3.11. Here's the error message:

```
LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::jupyter_latex_envs-1.4.6-pyhd8ed1ab_1002
location of failed script: /Users/xxxx/conda/anaconda3/envs/aws-generative-models-env/bin/.jupyter_latex_envs-post-link.sh
==> script messages <==
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: type 'List' is not subscriptable
```

It seems like the issue is related to the List type not being subscriptable, which might be due to compatibility issues with Python 3.11 used in my environment.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can offer insights on how to resolve this error? Specifically, I'm looking for a way to successfully complete the post-link script for jupyter_latex_envs without downgrading from Python 3.11, if possible.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please file [an Issue on the feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/jupyter_latex_envs-feedstock/issues). This is something that should likely be addressed in the recipe, rather than worked around by end-users.